# Switch setOnCheckedChangeListener looping after user input

Tags: java, android

I am trying to switch to dark mode immediately(without reloading) using a switch in a fragment.

The piece of code that I am using to do this is

`AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);`

This is working in testing but I want it to change to dark mode using the switch so my code is the following.

```
switch_us_dark_mode.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    // The toggle is enabled
                    Log.i("tag", "Hit Dark");
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                    editor.putString("theme", "dark");
                }

                if(!isChecked){
                    // The toggle is disable
                    Log.i("tag", "Hit Light");
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                    editor.putString("theme", "light");
                }
            }
        });
```

This is however looping after the first time I click on the switch.
[image]

I tried doing it on a thread but it threw me an error saying it must be run on the main thread.

I will move the switch below the button so that it doesnt look like its part of the form but thats besides the point.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
switch_us_dark_mode.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (buttonView.isPressed()) {
                    // The toggle is enabled
                    Log.i("tag", "Hit Dark");
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                    editor.putString("theme", "dark");
                } else {
                    // The toggle is disable
                    Log.i("tag", "Hit Light");
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                    editor.putString("theme", "light");
                }
            }
        });
```

Use "buttonView.isPressed()" instead of isChecked. Hope it works

You can also use the Checkbox instead of Switch and set the drawable to it, but only if above fails.

Comment: Good news. Its not looping anymore. It is however logging "Hit Dark" but also "Hit Light" right after. Same thing when I use a checkbox. I will google this. Might've opened a door for me. Thanks

Comment: I cant yet! Sorry haha

Comment: Forgot to  mention it doesn't actually switch to dark mode either. 
Dont know exactly what AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES); does.